# Polling SSIS execution status

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have an SSIS package that's launching another SSIS package in a *Foreach container*; because the container reports completion as soon as it launched all the packages it had to launch, I need a way to make it wait until all "child" packages have completed.

So I implemented a little sleep-wait loop that basically pulls the `Execution` objects off the SSISDB for the ID's I'm interested in.

The problem I'm facing, is that a grand total of 0 `Dts.Events.FireProgress` events get fired, and if I uncomment the `Dts.Events.FireInformation` call in the `do` loop, then every second I get a message reported saying 23 packages are still running... except if I check in SSISDB's *Active Operations* window I see that most have completed already and 3 or 4 are *actually* running.

What am I doing wrong, why wouldn't `runningCount` contain the number of *actually running* executions?

```
using ssis = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices;

public void Main()
{
    const string serverName = "REDACTED";
    const string catalogName = "SSISDB";

    var ssisConnectionString = $"Data Source={serverName};Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    var ids = GetExecutionIDs(serverName);

    var idCount = ids.Count();
    var previousCount = -1;

    var iterations = 0;

    try
    {
        var fireAgain = true;

        const int secondsToSleep = 1;
        var sleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToSleep);
        var maxIterations = TimeSpan.FromHours(1).TotalSeconds / sleepTime.TotalSeconds;

        IDictionary<long, ssis.Operation.ServerOperationStatus> catalogExecutions;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ssisConnectionString))
        {
            var server = new ssis.IntegrationServices(connection);
            var catalog = server.Catalogs[catalogName];
            do
            {
                catalogExecutions = catalog.Executions
                    .Where(execution => ids.Contains(execution.Id))
                    .ToDictionary(execution => execution.Id, execution => execution.Status);

                var runningCount = catalogExecutions.Count(kvp => kvp.Value == ssis.Operation.ServerOperationStatus.Running);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);

                //Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "ScriptMain", $"{runningCount} packages still running.", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

                if (runningCount != previousCount)
                {
                    previousCount = runningCount;
                    decimal completed = idCount - runningCount;
                    decimal percentCompleted = completed / idCount;
                    Dts.Events.FireProgress($"Waiting... {completed}/{idCount} completed", Convert.ToInt32(100 * percentCompleted), 0, 0, "", ref fireAgain);
                }

                iterations++;
                if (iterations >= maxIterations)
                {
                    Dts.Events.FireWarning(0, "ScriptMain", $"Timeout expired, requesting cancellation.", string.Empty, 0);
                    Dts.Events.FireQueryCancel();
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Canceled;
                    return;
                }
            }
            while (catalogExecutions.Any(kvp => kvp.Value == ssis.Operation.ServerOperationStatus.Running));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception.InnerException != null)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ScriptMain", exception.InnerException.ToString(), string.Empty, 0);
        }
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ScriptMain", exception.ToString(), string.Empty, 0);
        Dts.Log(exception.ToString(), 0, new byte[0]);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        return;
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

The `GetExecutionIDs` function simply returns all execution ID's for the child packages, from my metadata database.

Comment: I haven't used `c#` with SSIS, but can't you `execute` the package in `c#` as you can in SSDT? That way you get a result back before you continue processing.

Comment: @NickyvV the foreach loop is iterating metadata rows to determine what to parameterize the package with - I'm running 20+ instances of the same package in a loop, and I need them to run concurrently (that part works). The problem is that if I don't do anything then the "master" package reports completion before the "child" packages have completed running, and I can't have that; the above is a *script task* that follows the foreach container and basically waits for all "child" packages to complete. And I can't have `execute` be a blocking call because I need them concurrent.

Comment: Also, for some reason I can't break anywhere in that script - I mean I *can* put breakpoints, but they're never hit *despite the SSIS control flow showing the red dot in the script task box*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-using the same connection at every iteration. Turn this:

> ```
> using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ssisConnectionString))
> {
>     var server = new ssis.IntegrationServices(connection);
>     var catalog = server.Catalogs[catalogName];
>     do
>     {
>         catalogExecutions = catalog.Executions
>             .Where(execution => ids.Contains(execution.Id))
>             .ToDictionary(execution => execution.Id, execution => execution.Status);
> ```

Into this:

```
do
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ssisConnectionString))
    {
        var server = new ssis.IntegrationServices(connection);
        var catalog = server.Catalogs[catalogName];
        catalogExecutions = catalog.Executions
            .Where(execution => ids.Contains(execution.Id))
            .ToDictionary(execution => execution.Id, execution => execution.Status);
    }
```

And you'll get correct execution status every time. Not sure why the connection can't be reused, but keeping connections as short-lived as possible is always a good idea - and that's another proof.